# Does bootstrap allow scrollbars inside jumbotrons? if yes how do you add them?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to add multiple jumbotrons vertically and add a scrollbar in each jumbotron of fixed width. How do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
Follow this method.
Create a custom div inside the `<div class="jumbotron"> </div>`.
That is `<div class="jb"> </div>`
Example :

```
<div class="jumbotron"> 
     <div class="jb"> 
         This is jumbotron content 
     </div>
</div>
```

Then you have to add the following style to your style sheet.

```
.jb{
    height: 500px!important;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You can change the height according to your requirment.
The whole code as follows.
**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="jb">
          <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
          <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
          <hr class="my-4">
          <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
          <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
          </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Styles**

```
.jb{
    height: 500px!important;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Live Codeply Example**](https://codeply.com/v/ubnjepxwIC)